# Raspbian docker: Error response from daemon: cgroups: memory cgroup not supported on this system: unknown

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian

I am new to docker, I plug my PI3 to test some stuff and I'm already facing an error, I can't figured that out myself.

So I freshly install raspbian and docker.

That's my install log

[image: install log]

Then I try the classic hello-word test

and there is the log

[image: hello world test]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks 17.11.0 has the problem.

Could you try to install the old one as below ?

`$ sudo apt install docker-ce=17.09.0~ce-0~raspbian`

Or wait for the fix.

(2017.12.5)
It looks `2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch` has same issue. To avoid upgrading by `apt upgrade`, Do:
 `sudo apt-mark hold docker-ce`.
And `unhold` when it fixes.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution worked for me. RPi B+ v3 on 12/5/17.

Comment: Working here. Waiting a notification for the `unhold` :)

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to add `cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1` in `/boot/cmdline.txt` at the end of the line and reboot.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the implications of this? What does it do? Are there any negative side effects to be expected?

Comment: It enables memory control groups, since now it will probably be required to run docker, or at least it's not a bug in docker, it's related to how kernel manages memory, isolates resources.

Comment: This works on a brand new NOOBs based install with stretch. To be just a bit clearer, add these parameters to the end of the existing command line. Do not add them as a new line.